# Access #element in json object

Tags: javascript

Given the following:

[image]

How do I access the #text element? I've tried:

```
json.Viewer.StatPackages.StatPackage[0].Name.#text
json.Viewer.StatPackages.StatPackage[0].Name.text
json.Viewer.StatPackages.StatPackage[0].Name.text()
json.Viewer.StatPackages.StatPackage[0].Name.ToString()
```

Thanks!

Comment: Square bracket notation, just like your `[0]`. This lets you pass the result of any expression. In your case, you'd just use a string literal `"#text"`. So it's `.Name["#text"]`

Comment: @CrazyTrain That worked put it as an answer and I'll mark it:
json.Viewer.StatPackages.StatPackage[0].Name["#text"]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Square bracket notation, just like your `[0]`. This lets you pass the result of any expression. In your case, you'd just use a string literal `"#text"`. So it's `.Name["#text"]`.